# How to show customers the description of an IAP?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm using

```
CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(productid);
```

This shows customers the IAP purchase dialog, but doesn't show them the description which I entered in the Windows Store Dev center. It only shows them the name of the IAP.
So how do I get the description to show?

(I checked [ProductPurchaseDisplayProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.productpurchasedisplayproperties.aspx)   but it specifically states:

> Description ... Windows Phone only. This is an internal product
>   description.

And I'm not referring to Windows phone, rather to Windows UWP on PCs.)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add information of IAP product in your purchase dialog, I suggest you to add one customized UI dialog, you can get description by using [ProductListing class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.productlisting) **description property**, and then you may need to add button that can transfer the Store purchase dialog when it is clicked, Please pay attention that this dialog can not be modified.

**Update:**
Firstly, it is not possible to modify the store purchase UI.

Secondly, I know you have entered the description of IAPs in the dashboard, and you can get the IAPs's description property by [**ProductListing**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.productlisting) class and show in customized UI dialog to let users know what these are, how to use. Then you may need to use the **RequestPurchaseAsync methods** to transfer purchase UI to let users purchase Add-ons.

Hope it clarifies.

Comment: That class is _received_ from [ListingInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.listinginformation) which "Provides the listing info that describes the app in the Windows Store." So what exactly are you suggesting? I already entered that info in the Windows Store. Why is there even room to enter that if it isn't shown to customers?

Comment: @ispiro,Yes, I know you have entered these info in the Windows Store, as you mentioned before, there are only name and price of the IAP,  and you wan to add description IAP in the store purchase dialog, I think you may not do this. But you can add one customize UI dialog, and then you can add description of IAP by using [ProductListing class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.productlisting) in this dialog, but you may need to transfer the store purchase dialog to let customer pay.

Comment: `there are only name and price of the IAP` - Please read the question. And see [Description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/create-add-on-store-listings#description) (on MSDN).

Comment: @ispiro, I think that my misnomer let you misunderstand, I apologize for this. Please see my update, thanks.